# Eigen: Applying element wise absolute or power function

Tags: c++, eigen

As stated in the question, is there any way to do element wise operations such as absolute or power? There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do it in eigen surprisingly

Answer (score 10):

There are [several ways](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html). The first is to use the `.array()` function of a matrix. This then treats the object as a series of elements as opposed to a matrix. There are also some "cwise" functions that are essentially the same thing.

```
MatrixXf mat(20,20);
mat.setRandom();
MatrixXf mat2 = mat.array().abs(); // also mat.cwiseAbs()
MatrixXf mat3 = mat.array().pow(M_PI);
```

Comment: `MatrixXf mat2 = mat.array.abs();` it's a typo? should be `MatrixXf mat2 = mat.array().abs();` ?

Comment: @mrgloom yes, it’s a typo