Transform elements in an Eigen Vector to some constant to the power of the corresponding element
I am new to the Eigen library. I want to transform each element in a vector (or matrix) to some constant to the power of the corresponding element from the vector.
I want to do this operation efficiently because I may have a huge amount of elements. If possible, I would like to avoid a loop that traverses each element in the vector. There exist wise operations like .array().colwise().sum(). I was thinking about using some wise operation for doing this, if it exists.
Example:
int c = 3;
Vector<int, 3> v = { 1, 2, 3 }
v = pow(v, c);   // < pseudocode
std::cout << v;

Desired output:
 3  9 27

Explanation: {c^1, c^2, c^3} = {3^1, 3^2, 3^3} = {3, 9, 27}
Note that this question is not about raising each element to a constant (which is not complicated), but about raising a constant to the power of the corresponding element (which I find more complicated).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764844/eigen-applying-element-wise-absolute-or-power-function

std::transform would work too. Did you try anything? Why not? Even a simple loop would do the job

btw what you want to do is inherently inefficient. If you want to get powers of 3 there are better ways than to compute them seperately n-times. You only need to compute 3^max(v) once and remember the intermediate results

@rafix07 I don't think the link you posted is relevant because it shows how to raise each element to a certain power, not to raise a given base to powers given in the array elements. Am I wrong ?

How do you want to get to {3^1, 3^2, 3^3} from v = pow(v, 5); ?

"I want to avoid a loop that traverses each element in the vector." If you really want to update your whole vector contents, you cannot avoid iterating over it (except if you reassign a new one).

@pptaszni, that line is just pseudocode. I'm not really trying to use that. That's just an example of what I look for.
@rafix07, as @wohlstad pointed out, I think that link is not relevant in this case.
@463035818_is_not_an_ai, I'll try std::transform

@Fareanor regarding your [deleted] answer: I now see that Eigen Matrix does support STL-like iterator - at least from a certain version (see here). I posted an answer using a ranged-based loop (instead of std::transform). You can consider to update your answer demonstrating the std::transform approach. Note that pow is not suitable for integer exponantiation.

@wohlstad You are completely right, i misunderstood what OP wanted.

@AnselmoGPP you should not edit you question in a way that invalidates existing answer(s). That is the reason I rolled back you last edits. Please post a new question (you can refer to this question in it for context).  BTW - regarding your edit about c being possibly float - I already addressed that issue in my answer. You can consider to accept it if it solves the original question you posted.

@wohlstad, sorry if I invalidated any answer. I'm just trying to make my question more complete because I discovered some missing points. I just want to perform that computation efficiently using Eigen tools.

@AnselmoGPP it's OK, no real harm done. But since I already answered your question as it was posted originally (and I believe I gave a valid answer), the guideline in StackOverflow dictates that you should post a new question. I hope you can see that it is quite a fair rule, given the time people invest trying to answer and help others. Also your original question has some merit to it as is, and the answer might benefit future visitors of the site.

You mentioned that you would like to avoid traversing each element in the Vector.
This is not really possible. In order to update each element you must traverse the Vector. Even the element-wise operations in Eigen itself hide an internal iteration.
Since Eigen Vector (which is actually a type alias for Matrix of dim 1) support STL-like iterators, you can use a ranged-based loop to update the elements.
This is demonstrated below:
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int ipow(int base, int exp) {
    int result = 1;
    for (;;) {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp)
            break;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    int c = 3;
    Eigen::Vector<int, 3> v = { 1, 2, 3 };

    for (auto & elem : v) {
        elem = ipow(c, elem);
    }   

    for (auto const & elem : v) {
        std::cout << elem << ",";
    }
}

Output:
3,9,27,

Live demo
Note:
Since you are dealing with int values, I did not use pow which is meant for floating point values. Instead I used an int based exponantiation function. This functions assumes the exponent is non-negative. You can use the standard pow if you actually have float or double values. Note that if your Vectors values can be negative int is not a proper type for it because after exponantiation is will require non-integer values.

Update:
Following the comment below by @Homer512, if you prefer to use only an Eigne expression in this case, you can use:
v = Eigen::Array3i::Constant(c).binaryExpr(v.array(), &ipow);

To aid inlining you can replace the ipow function pointer with a lambda expression.
This approach has advantages (being able to combine with other Eigen expressions, one line initialization of an array), and disadvantages (readability, and isolation from other transformations you might wish to apply element-wise).

If you want to hide the loop inside an Eigen expression, you could write v = Eigen::Array3i::Constant(c).binaryExpr(v.array(), &ipow); However, you may want to replace the function pointer with a lambda or functor struct since GCC doesn't inline the function pointer

@Homer512 do you see any advantage of using an Eigen expression over a ranged-based loop ? (or over std::transform ?)

Depends on the context. You can make it part of a larger Eigen expression or directly initialize a new array from it in a single statement. OTOH it certainly isn't the easiest expression to read and isolating it from the rest of the math means the rest can remain vectorized while the integer power is not.

@Homer512 this makes sense. Added an update to my answer based on your comments.
